# AJAX status 200 fires error on PHP echo of json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Everything works fine with following program, except AJAX error fires:

javascript:

```
var data = {
    email: 'me@gmail.com',
    password: 'secretword'
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "application/json",
    url: "http://localhost/CFBserver/validateUser.php",
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

php:

```
    <?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cfbdata');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";

    if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($numrows > 0) {
        $message = array('result' => 'found',
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password,
        );
    } else {
        $message = array('result' => 'Not found',
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password,
        );
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($message);

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

This is what console displays:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {"result":"found","email":"me@gmail.com","password":"secretword"}
    </body>
</html>
```

So php finds the record in the mysql database but on return to AJAX, error fires. Why is this?

Comment: your open to SQL injection

Comment: your `error` and your `success` functions are identical so how do you know which is being trigged?

Comment: I do realize AJAX 'error' and 'success' fire the same code. But rest assured, I have confirmed 'error' is firing. Also, this is test code so I'm not concerned with security vulnerabilities at this stage of development.

Comment: Status 200 is not an error. That means success

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you change `dataType` to just `JSON`? Also, how do you know it's your error method firing when they both do exactly the same thing...

Comment: Changing dataType to json doesn't have any effect.

Comment: how about removing the `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX is expecting a JSON response, but is getting HTML. That's why the request returns status code 200 (= OK), but your JS won't work.

PHP's `json_encode` doesn't add HTML by itself, so you're probably outputting to a template (or you've wrapped your PHP in HTML).

As others have also mentioned, you're open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). There is also no way to be sure your error method is firing, since both your AJAX' `error` and `success` do the same thing.

Comment: Right. But where do the html tags come from? I'm not adding them.

Comment: @dru37 It says so in my answer: you're probably outputting to a template or you've wrapped your PHP in HTML.

Comment: How do I avoid outputting to a template? I'mean not sure what that means.